# Days of the Week On Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to do something with the days of the week. I have a cell on Sheet1 called 'Yr Overview' where a user inputs the day of the week.

On a second page I am reference thing by using =left('Yr Overview'!A1,1) so that is a user inputs a day like Sunday, if just shows it as an S. I have it working up to this point. Now I am trying to make that cell effect others on the same sheet.

So that is A1 = S A2 = M (S + 1 day) A3 = T (M + 1 day) etc.. I seem to be unable to do this, so I am just asking if this is possible? Or would I need to use VBA to achieve this.

Comment: Look at `WEEKDAY`.

Comment: That doesn't actually help does it? Might be being an idiot, but I swear that just outputs numeric content and not weekdays which I can trim down.

Comment: How is user entering day of week? As text or as a date?

Comment: @AlexP Weekday? How does it work for this?

Comment: @AlexP Just as a day. They input Sunday, I just trim that down to an S (or maybe Sun I'm not sure yet) but I want the rest of the values in the column to basically be +1 day from that one

Answer (score 1):

Try this in A2 and copy down:

```
=INDEX({"MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT","SUN"},MATCH(UPPER(LEFT(A1,3)),{"SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"},0))
```

[image]

Comment: How would this be modified to for A2 to be the same say as A1?

Comment: You would want a different formula; `=UPPER(LEFT(A1,3))` then adjust the firs formula in A3 to refer to A2 and not A1.

Comment: Isn't that the same formula? I would just want to Sunday (user input) then SUN MON TUE etc.. not already start+1 days after A1

Comment: That is what it would do.  If A1 = "Sunday" and the formula in A2 was `=UPPER(LEFT(A1,3))`  Then in A3 down you would have: `=INDEX({"MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT","SUN"},MATCH(UPPER(LEFT(A1,3)),{"SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"},0))`.  A2 would be `SUN` A3 would be `MON` and so on. @JamesPavett

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. Enter this formula in cell `A1` and drag to the right.

```
=LEFT(TEXT(MATCH('Yr Overview'!$A$1,{"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"},0)+COLUMN()-1,"dddd"))
```

[image]

Comment: Edit cause I did something slightly wrong. It actually starts on a Tuesday for some reason, despite input being sunday on A1

Comment: @JamesPavett This works only if you start from A1 and then to right. If not you may have to alter this formula

Answer (score 1):

Below solution helps only if in case of input date instead of day.

```
A1- 07/14/2017
A2=TEXT(A1+1,"dddd")
A3=TEXT(A1+2,"dddd")
A4=TEXT(A1+3,"dddd")
A5=TEXT(A1+4,"dddd")
A6=TEXT(A1+5,"dddd")
A7=TEXT(A1+6,"dddd")
```

Answer (score 0):

In `A2` add this formula:

```
=IF(ROW()<8,IF(FIND(LOWER(LEFT(Sheet1!$A$1,3)),"montuewedthufrisatsun",1)+(ROW()-1)*3<=LEN("montuewedthufrisatsun"),UPPER(LEFT(MID("montuewedthufrisatsun",FIND(LOWER(LEFT(Sheet1!$A$1,3)),"montuewedthufrisatsun",1)+(ROW()-1)*3,3),1)),UPPER(LEFT(MID("montuewedthufrisatsun",FIND(LOWER(LEFT(Sheet1!$A$1,3)),"montuewedthufrisatsun",1)-(ROW()*-3+24),3),1))),OFFSET(A2,-7,0))
```

Assumes day is input in cell A1 on `Yr Overview`